# Indy's TIdHTTPProxyServer: How to filter requests?

Tags: delphi, indy10

I'm using an TIdHTTPProxyServer to implement a simple HTTP proxy, but I'd like now to block some connections if they match certain URLs. Which event and/or component is best to accomplish that? Indy documentation is not too explicative. :(

Thanks!

Comment: TIdHTTPProxyServer simply cannot do that, have to edit its code

Comment: @Worm Regards yes it can, see my answer...

Comment: @Worm and @Dorin: It is of course possible, see my answer. ;)

Comment: @jachguate is it possible to alter the response too ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a basic filter you can use the OnHTTPBeforeCommand event handler (which fires before the command is sent to the HTTP server).

Inspect the Context parameter properties, you'll find useful:

```
Context.Command
Context.OutboundClient.Host
Context.OutboundClient.Port
Context.Document
Context.Headers
```

I never tried to stop the PassTrough at this time, but I bet you can do it by just raising an exception at that point if you determine there's a block rule match.

Comment: Your answer made me realize I had been using an old version of Indy. It has improved a lot, at least the parts I checked.

Answer (score 1):

the component has a "OnConnect" event, double-click it and add this code:

```
if AContext.Connection.Socket.Binding.PeerIP = '127.0.0.1' then
  AContext.Connection.Disconnect;
```

replace 127.0.0.1 with your filter, this is just a "extremely basic example", same applies to other Indy servers which have a "OnConnect" event.

Comment: -1: OnConnect will fire when the HTTP **client** connects to your proxy, not when the proxy connects to the remote server (that's up to you, TidHTTPProxy does not implement it), and no URL is still available. Unless you're only checking which "internal" IPs are allowed to send HTTP requests outside, that's not the correct way.

Comment: @ldsandon: `TIdHTTPProxyServer` does implement connections to the remote server for you (otherwisee it would not be much of a proxy).  See the `TIdHTTPProxyServerContext.OutboundClient` property.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau: you're right, I got confused with a proxy implementation I did some time ago using only TidHTTPServer.